# How to do string with dot operator extension using a variable

Tags: python

Basically I am trying to do following code snippet

```
a = "abc"
all = dir(a)
print all
print a.__add__
```

The fourth line I would like to do using a variable (in a loop) rather than operating each time, like following (but did not go smooth):

```
print a.all[0]
tmp = a+'.'+all[0]
print tmp
eval tmp
```

Please suggest me how can I do this through a loop using a variable like:

```
  for i in all :
      print a.i
```

Comment: `a.i` is a `class` action ? starting point `str to class` or ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, you don't use `eval` as it is considered unsafe and bad practice overall.

According to python docs [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) outputs list of strings, representing valid attributes on the object

> Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. **With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.**

There's a built-in method to get a member of class/instance by name: [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) (and it's sister methods `setattr` and `hasattr`)

```
a = "QWE"

for member in dir(a):
    print getattr(a, member)
```

Prints

```
<method-wrapper '__add__' of str object at 0x0000000002FF1688>
<class 'str'>
<method-wrapper '__contains__' of str object at 0x0000000002FF1688>
<method-wrapper '__delattr__' of str object at 0x0000000002FF1688>
<built-in method __dir__ of str object at 0x0000000002FF1688>
str(object='') -> str
str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to cast it all as a string first. Is this what you're looking for?

```
a = "abc"
all = dir(a)
for i in all :
      print eval( 'a.{1}'.format(a, i) )
```

Outputs

```
<method-wrapper '__add__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<type 'str'>
<method-wrapper '__contains__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<method-wrapper '__delattr__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
str(object) -> string

Return a nice string representation of the object.
If the argument is a string, the return value is the same object.
<method-wrapper '__eq__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<built-in method __format__ of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<method-wrapper '__ge__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<method-wrapper '__getitem__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<built-in method __getnewargs__ of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<method-wrapper '__getslice__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
<method-wrapper '__gt__' of str object at 0x1ea7698>
...
```